# App occasionally crashes when reading barcodes

Tags: android, cordova, barcode-scanner

I just got started with PhoneGap (version 2.5) and am developing an Android app that will be able to read QR code (and eventually NFC tags). I'm using [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner) plugin for reading the QR codes. I've set up a simple test-application with a button that launches the scanner and a p-tag under it that will display the content of the QR code. This is the code that starts the scanner

```
scan: function() {
    try {
        window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan( function(args) {
            console.log("Scanner result: \n" +
                "text: " + args.text + "\n" +
                "format: " + args.format + "\n" +
                "cancelled: " + args.cancelled + "\n");
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = args.text;
            console.log(args);
        });
    } catch(ex) {
        console.log(ex.message);
    }
}
```

The code works most of the times, but occasionally it will crash after a code has been read (the scanner captures a tag and reports that URL/plain text/whatever has been found, but then crashes when it's trying to return to my application). I've found no particular pattern for the crashes, the same code can sometimes be scanned and sometimes it crashes. Here is the error messages from LogCat.

```
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.package.hellophonegap/com.package.hellophonegap.HelloPhonegap}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=195543262, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.SCAN flg=0x80000 (has extras) }} to activity {com.package.hellophonegap/com.package.hellophonegap.HelloPhonegap}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2742)
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2235)
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3692)
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240)
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=195543262, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.SCAN flg=0x80000 (has extras) }} to activity {com.package.hellophonegap/com.package.hellophonegap.HelloPhonegap}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3319)
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2729)
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325):    ... 13 more
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325):    at org.apache.cordova.DroidGap.onActivityResult(DroidGap.java:849)
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5293)
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3315)
03-07 13:46:57.478: E/AndroidRuntime(28325):    ... 14 more
```

The problem is that I've no idea how to interpret the error messages or how to debug the application. Any pointers in how I could further troubleshoot the error would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any luck with this? I have an identical issue. I'm using the same BarcodeScanner plugin on an Android PhoneGap application on Android 4.1.1 OS and seem to be getting pretty much identical error messages to yours. I got the errors 3 times in a row just now, and have never experienced the errors before - and I haven't touched the barcode scanning code - neither my code which invokes it nor the native Java source code for it, so I don't know what's going on.

Comment: It's odd that you say it will only occasionally crash. For me, I have never experienced this error before, then all of a sudden today the barcode scanner won't work at all without changing anything. I tried cleaning my solution, rebooting my phone and making sure my phone settings were all the usual stuff ... but I've had no luck with this so far. It's a very annoying mystery!

Comment: So, I just tried running my application on a HTC One X (a much superior phone in terms of the hardware technical specification) and found it works perfectly. Is it possible that there is a performance issue? Perhaps the application is using too much memory on the HTC Desire where I've been getting errors? Although I don't quite see how that could be the case because it was working yesterday for me - and I've added nothing else to my application (in recent days I've added more code, but I haven't done anything that would extra strain on the phone's main memory).

Comment: I don't think it was a performance issue for me since I was using my Nexus 4. I actually gave up on this and ended up developing my application natively.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a factory reset of the phone OS. I found that once I had done that, the issues no longer occurred.

I have little idea of why it wasn't working on the phone and what was actually causing the errors though. I'll update this post if I understand what the issue was. The only thing I'm almost sure is that the problem is caused by an issue with the operating system on my phone (HTC Desire).

I should note that the version of Android I have installed is a Cyanogen port, since Android 4.2 doesn't normally work on HTC Desires due to memory constraints.

As mentioned above, I did not experience these errors on a HTC One X running Android 4.2.